# General formula for sum of polygonal numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation

EDIT- Thanks to Jair taylor I got the answer but now my question is- What will be the sum in $p^{th}$ dimension??

Polygonal numbers is a sequence of numbers. The $k^{th}$ term of a n-polygonal series is the minimum number of dots it would require us to make a n-sided polygon with k dots in each side. We all have heard about triangular series.It is one such example known as 3-gon series.

Here is an illustration of how to arrange these dots in a triangular series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number
in the top right corner you could see the diagram.

The series of square numbers is- 1,4,9,16,25,...   This is a 4-gonal series.

Again illustratio for 5-gon series-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number

You could find more such by searching them. (Octagonal numbers also know as star numbers are interesting).

My question is- Can we derive a formula for the $k^{th}$ term of a n-gon series in general? Can we derive a formula for the sum of first k terms of a n-gon series in general?

These sequences might help to analyze a pattern.

3-gon - 1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,...

4-gon - 1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,...

5-gon - 1,5,12,22,35,51,70,92,...

8-gon - 1,8,21,40,65,96,133,176,...

Comment: hopefully, or pari/gp's ispolygonal() is lying.

Comment: Wikipedia has a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number#Formula)

Comment: Thanks Jair Taylor. But what about the sum?

Comment: @JayantJha Since the formula is quadratic, you can expand it and use $\sum_{k=1}^n k = n(n+1)/2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1) / 6$.

Comment: @JayantJha You will have to specify what you mean by the $p$-th dimension, but take a look at, e.g., [figurate numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FigurateNumber.html).  In general you will have a degree-$p$ polynomial.  To sum up arbitrary polynomials you can use [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Comment: @Jair taylor there are polygonal numbers as well as polyhedral numbers. Can there be a formula for which I can calculate the the sum of first k terms of a n-sided p(2 or 3) dimensioned figure numbers. If the formula works for 2-dimension and 3-dimension figures in genera, it should work for 4-dimensional figures as well. So can that help us know something about the fourth-dimension??? Bit advanced for me to do all this. I will definately require help.